# Get Sub Categories with Parent category in the same request

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my migration, I made `column` called `parent_id` and it takes `0` if this category is a parent category else it takes the `id` of its parent.

what I want to do is in one request I want to fetch all parent categories and inside each parent `array` of its sub-category

```
public function index()
{
    return Category::where('parent_id', '0')->each(function ($parent) {
        Category::where('parent_id', $parent->id)->get();
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: have you set proper relations on the Category Model?

Comment: no there is not a relation they are in the same table